# Connecting to socket.io using C# client, but using/joining room

Tags: c#, node.js, socket.io

I'm using socket.io with rooms without any problem with Node and React.

In my server side, I've this piece if code:

```
socket.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('user connected');

  let room = socket.handshake['query']['r_var'];
  socket.join(room);
  console.log('user joined room #' + room);
});
```

And this is how I connecting from client side:

```
import openSocket from 'socket.io-client';
openSocket(`${readerUrl}:${wsPort}`, {
              query: 'r_var=dynamic_room'
            })
```

I need to do the same, but with C#. Although I found several examples for C#, none uses rooms. Anybody have some example?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Sockets don't have a concept of rooms.  The code you posted calls it a room, but it looks like it's just a socket.

Comment: Please, before vote down my answer, check this official link: [link] (https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/)

Comment: That's a socket.io specific feature.  Have a look here: https://github.com/IBM/socket-io.  It's a C# client for Socket.io.  It should have the room functionality you seek.

Comment: And this one.  https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet.  Although it was recently deprecated, it has full-feature capability.

Comment: Yeah I know... I just tried not to use deprecated packages... But seem like the only way.

Comment: The source code is available for both packages.  Have at it.

Comment: I'm wondering why the question has -1... It's a good formatted question, and I specify I'm using socket.io. Anyway...

Comment: It wasn't my downvote, but your question essentially reads "I need some copy/paste code from the Internet but didn't find any.  Can you look for me?"  Some community members probably find that to be lazy.

Comment: It's my downvote, and it's for the reasons that Robert specified. You're basically asking us to write your code for you, or find some code for you. We don't exist to do those things. With sufficient research, you could have found socket.io clients. Stack Overflow is not a substitute for basic research.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself and I share the solution for who need it too.

The used package was https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet. It's deprecated but work very well and it's pretty updated.

To pass a query (used to join rooms on socket.io), you need to use a var of type "Dictionary".

```
var query = new Dictionary<string, string>();
query.Add("room", "test");

var options = new IO.Options();
options.Query = query;

var Socket = IO.Socket("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3001", options);
```

As you can see I'm not C# programmer, it's probably that you can improve the code.

Comment: But remember this package will only work 2.x server. It doesn't support socket.io 3.x & 4.x server